# Retrive the rows/data from datagridview after the application has been closed

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, devexpress, oledb

I have a dialog form here where a user can upload a file from Excel and import and display to the datagrid view. However, my problem is when the user closes the application or form, the datagridview was empty and reset.

My question is how can I retrieve its data and display it, every time the user will open the form. Is it possible if the data was not saved in the database and will only based on the uploaded or imported Excel file? And if the user has uploaded a new Excel, I want to replace the existing rows or data in the datagridview.

I really hope you would help.

Below you can find my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class frmSupplier


Private Sub btn_upload_supplier_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_upload_supplier.Click
        Try
            If btn_upload_supplier.Text = "New" Then
                Dim Openfile As New OpenFileDialog
                Openfile.ShowDialog()
                txtpath_supplier.Text = Openfile.FileName
                Label1.Text = txtpath_supplier.Text
                If txtpath_supplier.Text = Nothing Then
                Else
                    btn_upload_supplier.Text = "Upload"
                End If
            ElseIf btn_upload_supplier.Text = "Upload" Then
                Dim dtItemlist As New DataTable
                Dim obj As New Basegeneral

                Try
                    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
                    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
                    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
                    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;  Data Source=" + txtpath_supplier.Text.ToString() + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
                    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
                    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
                    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
                    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
                    dg_details.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

                    MyConnection.Close()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.ToString, "Error:")
                End Try

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.ToString, "Error:")
        End Try

    End Sub




    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = GridView1.GetDataRow(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle)

            If row.Item(0).ToString = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please select supplier to remove", "KCC Retail System")
                Return
            End If

            If DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove supplier  '" & row.Item(0) & "'?", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                MessageBox.Show("Supplier  " & row.Item(0) & "  has been removed!", "KCC Retail System")
                GridView1.DeleteRow(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle)
            Else
                Return
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error :")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_clear.Click
        btn_upload_supplier.Text = "New"
        txtpath_supplier.Text = ""
    End Sub
```

The form will be open when the user click the button and it will display as a dialog (ShowDialog).

Comment: can you provide examples of what you have and what you're trying to do?

Comment: are those tags chosen randomly or do they all apply somehow?

Comment: @ashleedawg , yes , it applied somehow, because i use dev express grid view, oledb and ms excel

Comment: Please don't name a DataAdapter as MyCommand. There is a Command object in ADO.net and it makes your code confusing.

Comment: @Mary, sorry about that I just copy it from the internet.

Comment: Is it true that the changes made in the DataGridView are not saved back to the Excel file or anywhere else? What is dt and where is it declared?

Comment: @Mary , oh sorry again, don't mind the dt, I just try to put there when I was trying to solve the problem. When the user exits the form, the information and changes made in datagridview are deleted. And when user opens the form again, the datagridview has empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

To save and then re-hydrate the contents of a DataGridView you can use a binary formatter.

```
Imports System.IO
Import System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim FileName As String = "MyData.dat" 'Will save in bin directory
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
        ' 1. Create an instance of a Binary Formatter
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        ' 2. Create a file stream passing in (the name of the file to create, mode: Create, access: Write, share: none)
        Using fs As Stream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            ' 3. use the Serialize method of the Binary Formatter passing in the file stream(file name, create, write, no share) And the object
            bf.Serialize(fs, dt)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFillFromFill_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFillFromFill.Click
        Dim FileName As String = "MyData.dat"
        Dim dt As DataTable
        ' 1. Create an instance of Binary Formatter
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter()
        ' 2. Get an instance of a FileStream for the OpenRead method of File passing in (the fileName)
        Using fs As Stream = File.OpenRead(FileName)
            ' 3. cast back to original object, the Deserialize method of the Binary Formatter passing in the File Stream
            dt = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), DataTable)
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
```